Filter to remove starting zeros from numeric array in php
I want to create a callback function to remove from a numeric array the given values.
Given this array: [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 4, 5, 2, 0, ];
I want to create a callable function to be passed to array_filter that will return this array: [1, 0, 3, 4, 5, 2, 0, ];. I have seen in this answer the use of array_filter: Deleting an element from an array in PHP but is not exactly what I need because this option will remove all the 0s from the array and I need to keep the ones that are not leading.
I have created this function that cycles the array and returns the expected array, but I want to use something more efficient:
function removeLeading( int $array_values[], $to_remove = 0 )
{
    $is_leading = true;
    $result = [];
    foreach( $array_values as $value ) {
        if( ( $value == $to_remove ) && ( $is_leading == true ) ) {
            // Do nothing because it is a leading $to_remove
        }
        else {
            $result[] = $value;
            $is_leading = false;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}


Incidentally, "trailing" is the wrong word here - that would refer to elements at the end of the array; elements at the start of the array could be called "leading"

How do you feel about hacky solutions? str_split(preg_replace('/0{2,}/', '', implode('', [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 4, 5, 2, 0, ])))) (This also assumes all values are single digit integers, 10 etc could fault)

Related: How to get first non zero value and last non zero value indexes in array? and Get first non-null value from a flat array and PHP array: get first not empty value no matter the key

From the other end: Find last non-zero value in array. Another related page: How to get first occurrence non zero key value pair from any associative array

And How to find first array element with value greater than X in PHP?

array_filter is not the right tool for this job, because it tests every element of the array, and the most efficient algorithm for this task is probably to stop iterating once you hit the first non-zero element.
Then, rather than copying the remaining elements to the output one by one, you could use array_slice to produce a new array starting at a particular offset.
$firstElementToKeep = 0;
foreach ( $input as $value ) {
   // As soon as we find a non-zero element, stop looking
   if ( $value !== 0 ) {
      break;
   }
   // Track the offset we reach
   $firstElementToKeep++;
}
$output = array_slice($input, $firstElementToKeep);

With the example input in your question, $firstElementToKeep reaches 4, which is the index of the 1, so we "slice" from there to the end of the array, and get the desired output.
In most cases, the difference will be completely undetectable, but for a very large array, there might be a noticeable saving from not running as many comparisons, and not having to resize the output array in memory as more elements are added.

Hi, thanks, great answer. I was wondering if there is a way to avoid using a loop. (I know in the end, there is always going to be a loop behind the courtain) but you know, when doing stuff like this, you use regex, still your answer does the gob perfectly

@Tales The only possible optimization I see is to return the original array if $firstElementToKeep equals 0.

@Tales As you say, there's going to be a loop underneath somewhere, at least as long as you're using a high-level data structure like a PHP array rather than finding some crazy CPU-specific trick with raw memory. Using something like array_filter would move the loop to C, but at the cost of repeatedly switching back to PHP context to run the callback, which is probably a net reduction in performance. I can't stress enough, this is almost certainly an irrelevant micro-optimization, so the more important thing is having code that's easy to understand (which regexes are notoriously not!)

Yes, you can do this with array filter. The trick is to accumulate the first values and return false if it is still zero.
This will work only if you want to left trim a falsy value.
$filtered = array_filter(
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 4, 5, 2, 0],
    function($value) use (&$sum) { return $sum += $value === 0 ? false : $value; }
);

gives you
array (
  4 => 1,
  5 => 0,
  6 => 3,
  7 => 4,
  8 => 5,
  9 => 2,
  10 => 0,
)

But if you want to get rid of the original indices use
$filtered = [...array_filter(
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 4, 5, 2, 0],
    function($value) use (&$sum) { return $sum += $value === 0 ? false : $value; }
)];

to reindex and have it like so
array (
  0 => 1,
  1 => 0,
  2 => 3,
  3 => 4,
  4 => 5,
  5 => 2,
  6 => 0,
)


Splatpacking is more concise but less performant than calling array_values().

@mickmackusa The game changed with PHP 8.x. See example of the answer: https://3v4l.org/N8hNN PHP has learned to optmize it over a function call.

Looks like splat packing is consistently worse until 8.3.

@mickmackusa Please correct me if I am wrong. For me it looks like spat packing is faster since 8.3 than array_values. I do interpret lower duration as better. https://ibb.co/3zfZGhz

I don't think we are disagreeing.  The performance difference is negligible since 8.3
